# How can I access a directory outwith my programs with Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, file, file-access

I am trying to list the files of a directory on Android through flutter, I am using `file_picker` to access it but it lists nothing even for a directory full of files.

I have tried opening a directory with files in it and printing it out:

```dart
void _pickDirectory() async {
  final path = await FilePicker.platform.getDirectoryPath();
  if (path == null) {
    print('Canceled');
  } else {
    final directory = Directory(path);
    final files = directory.listSync();
    print(files);
  }
}
```

but it just prints out an empty array.
I've added

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

to my android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml and reinstalled the app but it still shows no files.

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: On Android it is impossible for normal Apps to access arbitrary paths  in the file system. This is only possible for system apps, or if you root your device.

Comment: @Ber Well that was simple, so what I want to do isn't possible. Oh well, thanks for the help.

Comment: are you testing on an emulator? also you need the check `if (path != '/')`. see https://pub.dev/documentation/file_picker/latest/file_picker/FilePicker/getDirectoryPath.html

Comment: @Hydra I've tested it on both my Fairphone and on an Pixel 3a emulator and they both return a working path (i.e. not '/') but no files are listed

Comment: @Ber In that case how do Obsidian and Syncthing manage access to any directory?

Comment: @Alex Good question. The version of SyncThing is not able to access any directory, but still a lot. As the source code is public on GitHub, may you can find out, or ask the developers.